How to remove the collapsing 'feature' from VS Code notebooks' left border?
When I am working with notebooks in VS Code, there's this very thin area in the interface at the left of the notebook cell that collapses the entire cell if you click on it. Since it is hard to explain where it is with words, I decided to record a small video.
I would like to know if you can disable this at all.
I tried looking at the settings but didn't see any obvious way to disable it.

In settings.json:
"notebook.cellFocusIndicator": "border",

I don't think that's the intended purpose of that setting, but it seems to achieve this as a side-effect.
